# ElastiSearch NEST - $Type invert mapping during update

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using dynamic mapping during index creation:

```
 var node = new Uri(_settings.ElasticSearchEndPoint);
            var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(node);
            var _settings = new ConnectionSettings(
                connectionPool,
                new HttpConnection(),                    
                new SerializerFactory((jsonSettings, nestSettings) => jsonSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto));

            _settings
                .MapDefaultTypeNames(m => m.Add(typeof(Activity), _settings.ElasticSearchDefaultType))
                .DefaultIndex(_settings.ElasticSearchDefaultIndex); 

            _esClient = new ElasticClient(_settings);
            var responseMap = _esClient.Map<Activity>(ms => ms
                                .AutoMap()
                                .Properties(ps => ps
                                    .Nested<IActivityDetail>(n => n
                                        .Name(c => c.Details)
                                    .AutoMap()
                                    )
                                )
                            );
```

Thanks to this row:

`new SerializerFactory((jsonSettings, nestSettings) => jsonSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto));`

when I insert a new Activity with details, details are mapped with the correct type:

```
"details": [
            {
              "$type": "XXX.Plugin.Domain.Service, XXX.Plugin.Test",
              "id": 1,
              "itemInstanceId": 3650,
              "defect": 1,
              "operation": 1
            }
```

but when I update the document using:

```
var status = esClient.Update<Activity>(  
                 new DocumentPath<Activity>(activity), u => 
                        u.Doc(activity));
```

the document is regularly updated but the $Type goes to end of the details type like:

```
"details": [
        {              
          "id": 1,
          "itemInstanceId": 3650,
          "defect": 1,
          "operation": 1
          "$type": "XXX.Plugin.Domain.Service, XXX.Plugin.Test",
        }
```

And the document could not be correctly mapped by Json anymore.
Any idea?

Comment: You can't rely on the ordering of properties in json; the json specification says that: _"An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs"_. What are you trying to do that requires `$type` to be the first property? Maybe there's a better/another way of achieving the end goal.

Comment: @RussCam when $type is the first property, the document is correctly mapped, when it is the last it doesn't. Why?

Comment: when you say _"correctly mapped"_, what do you mean? That the json representation of the POCO is not correct, or that the deserialization of the json to a POCO instance is not correct? Could you provide a small reproducble example?

Comment: The second: the deserializatin of the json throws an exception. 'Details' is a nested class that implements an interface. I use the $type key/value to correctly assgn the class. But after a simple update, reading again the document, the deserialization throws an error like 'cannot deserialize an interface'. But the insert and the query, before the update are always correct.

Comment: this sounds like a Json.NET issue. if you could put together a small reproducible example, I can look into it